# I can't seem to make password_verify() work

Tags: php, sql

I hash password before it is store into DB. When I want to get it back and compare with user input I always get "password does not match". I tried a lot of fixes but nothing seems to work. May be the problem is with my syntax, I am not good with php.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (password_verify($RegisteredPass, $row['pass']))
       {
           echo "tchd";
           echo "ID:".$row['id'] ."|Name:".$row['name']. "|User:".$row['user'];
           }
       else{
           echo "pass doesn`t match";
           
       }
    }
} else {
   
    echo "user not found";
}
```

Hashing password

```
$hassedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 12]);
```

I am not very concern about security, because it is just for a project. I just need to make it work.

### Edit

I changed while loop as was in "duplicate", but it still does not work. Any ideas why?

```
$sql = "SELECT pass, id, name, user FROM unityTut WHERE user='".$RegisterUser."'";

 $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            if (password_verify($RegisteredPass, $row['pass'])) {

                //Password matches, so create the session
                 
                

echo "Match";

            }else{
                echo  "The username or password do not match";
            }
```

Comment: What is the datatype and length of your password field in your database table?

Comment: Where does `$RegisteredPass` come from?

Comment: Are you sure the password is correctly stored into the DB? And with "correctly stored" I mean that the password field is a `VARCHAR(255)`

Comment: If you are not that interested in security, why are you increasing the `cost` value from its default of 10

Comment: here is a similar example 
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536293/php-password-hash-password-verify

Comment: Why are you fetching the row in a while loop. I would expect if you are checking the password it would be  for a single specific user. Maybe you should show us the query that gets the results you are processing

Comment: So, field in DB was not VARCHAR(255) but it is now. 
$RegisteredPass comes from C# from the user
I will change cost lower, but it is not a problem now

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729759/php-password-verify-not-working-with-database and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536293/php-password-hash-password-verify?noredirect=1&lq=1 solutions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP password\_hash(), password\_verify()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536293/php-password-hash-password-verify)

Comment: `I am not very concern about security, because it is just for a project. I just need to make it work.` You should get marked down for this attitude. It means when security *is* a concern you're tempted to make shortcuts or you fall into issues you would otherwise have resolved by learning the correct methods before it's critical.

Comment: Re your Edit. Good. This shows the problem is almost certainly your character set or your Database. Please show `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to output the structure of your MySQL

Comment: @Martin I am not sure what you want me to show. Do you need to see structure of my table user ? https://ibb.co/hMtsEm ?

Comment: @TomášTomHaverla yes, please edit your Q and add that graphic. Cheers

Comment: @TomášTomHaverla also show us where you set `$RegisteredPass`

Answer (score 1):

So it works now!

Code for login:

```
$sql = "SELECT pass, id, name, user FROM unityTut WHERE user='".$RegisterUser."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if (password_verify($RegisteredPass, $row['pass'])) {
        echo "Match";
    }else{
        echo  "The username or password do not match";
    }
// ...
```

`VARCHAR(255)` Seems to do the trick, but I had to delete all records and register new user. That seems to do the trick too.